# How to set the android:configChanges from manifest in the activity code

Tags: android, screen-orientation

For devices running < 3.x SDK it's enough to add only

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the manifest file so that onCreate method not to be called again on screen rotation, but on those running > 3.x this is not enough and an additional flag has to be added

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Now my question is how can I set the screenSize in the activity's Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to according to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). It'll work on both HC and pre-HC (provided that you target API 13+). That being said, it's really bad practice to handle configuration changes the way you do it. Try reading about `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `onSaveInstanceState()`.